# AngularJS integration with designers who don't know it

Tags: angularjs

I have been writing apps with AngularJS for a while now and have loved it.

However, recently I had to work with a designer who designed the HTML for the app. I took his app and added a host of angular directives into the code and got it to work. Some time later, he had to make changes to the design - and not knowing AngularJS had some trouble getting around it.

My question is - What is the best way to solve this problem? For example, jQuery with its DOM based binding wouldn't have these issues. So is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Interesting question. This could have an impact on our workflow at some stage. Maybe change the title to "designers who don't know it"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I decided to go with is as follows:

- Provide a standard set of class names to be used with functional names
- Wrote a ruby script using Nokogiri to detect class names and add directives etc.

Answer (score 1):

### Use a specific framework

This might not help you, but the solution we decided to use in our case is to have our HTML strictly following a specific framework syntax like *Bootstrap* or *Foundation*.

This way, our design cannot really apply modification on HTML which stay exclusively front-end area, but only apply it on CSS and eventually define specification on a "Sample page".

This solution is absolutely not perfect, but work for us.

### Teaching him angular

What about teaching him Angular ? It is a really popular framework, lots of documentation, and if he don't really need to know how to code in Angular, **just reading it might be possible** in a matter of days/weeks.

### What else ?

Please suggest any other options, it is an interesting topic but I don't see much alternative right now :(

---

--- Resources ---

After looking around I found this article but it feel pretty old to me :
https://medium.com/@minipai/angularjs-tutorial-for-designers-8c7dc63ca65f

Interesting discussion about it, might help :
http://maccg.com/2014/07/styling-assists-via-angularjs/

Comment: Yeah, this is one of the things that I have considered - to create strict templates and only alter styling. This is my last resort :) I wonder if there is a better alternative

Comment: What about teaching him Angular ? It is a really popular framework, lots of documentation, and if he don't really need to know how to code in Angular, just reading it might be possible in a matter of days/weeks. (I update my answer :))

Comment: @sebastienbarbier Teaching a designer Angular?! That's asking a lot. In an ideal world maybe but I'm sure the designer has enough on his/her plate to make that difficult.

Comment: Unfortunately, teaching Angular doesn't seem to be viable - In my case, the front-end application can have different templates, and that means different designers.

Comment: Sadely, I don't see much alternative than separating designing and integration ... designers need to provide a template guideline (like forza for exemple http://forza.ndevrstudios.com/#/) then developers need to use it and integrate the same code ... which should be easy if template are documented.